# How to Bind a GridView from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to bind a GridView?

I want to display my table data in a gridview.

I have createed SQL table `EmpDetail` with columns `ID, Name, Salary Data`

Answer (score 12):

Try below code according to your scenario

I hope it helps you

```cs
protected void GridviewBind ()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RapidProgramming;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=RPDB"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name,Salary FROM YOUR TABLE", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
              BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" 
              BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
              style="text-align: center; margin-left: 409px" Width="350px">
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
</asp:GridView>;
```

Comment: You do not need to close the connection (`con.Close();`) as the `IDisposable` implementation for the `SqlConnection` class calls `.Close()` on the connection for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        bindData();   
    }
}

public void bindData() {
        SqlConnection con=new SqlCponnection(ConnectionStrings);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from  Your TableName", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try {
            da.Fill(ds, "YourTableName");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Response.Write( e.Message);
        } finally {
            ds.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to run this code, you need to replace connectionstring's credentials myServerName\myInstanceName, myDataBase, myUsername, myPassword with yours

```
using System.Data;   
using System.Data.SqlClient;

string sConnectionString = @"Data Source=myServerName\myInstanceName;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(!IsPostBack)
        BindGridView();   
}

private void BindGridView() {             
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
    SqlConnection con = null;         

    try {
        string sQuery = "SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM EmpDetail";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con); 
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dt.Load(sdr);
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
    catch{ }
    finally{
        dt.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table1", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }

}

<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the SqlDataSource. You would move the SqlDataSource from the toolbox where it says Data, SqlDataSource. You would then configure the datasource using the smart tag. Then using the smart tag on the gridview, select the SqlDataSource you placed onto the aspx page. This is really quick and requires little to no coding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-us/Library/z72eefad.aspx this will show you a little bit more. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
use Class7917
select * from Emp
alter table Emp add images varchar(100)
sp_helptext 'usp_emp_insert_update'
alter proc usp_emp_insert_update  
@empid int,  
@name varchar(50),  
@cid int,  
@sid int,  
@dob datetime,  
@isactive int,  
@hobbies varchar(100),
@images varchar(100)  
as  
begin  
 if(@empid=0)  
  begin  
   insert into Emp(Name,cid,sid,dob,isactive,hobbies,images)  
   values(@Name,@cid,@sid,@dob,@isactive,@hobbies,@images)  
  end  
 else  
  begin  
   update Emp set Name=@name,cid=@cid,sid=@sid,  
   dob=@dob,isactive=@isactive,hobbies=@hobbies,images=@images   
   where EmpID=@empid  
  end  
end
truncate table Emp
```

Comment: Your effort posting a whole solution to the question (in 6 parts/answers) is appreciated, but it seems to be outside the typical SO format.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please complete a description instead of just writing source code.