# From Temp DataTable to Gridview

Tags: c#

I have a temp Datatable which gets information after search has been done.

I want to be able to take the information that's inside the Temp Table an transfer it over to gridview.

Can anyone tell me how this is able to be done?
I am able to take information from SQL server, But cannot figure out how to take it from a temp table due to I don't know what would need doing.

Comment: Read on "Binding data to GridView from DataBase".(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960601/how-to-bind-a-gridview-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're working with ASP.NET Winforms, that's the way you do it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<the info>);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fb_results", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}
```

You can create a class or a method which solves all the logic to return the DataTable that you want...

Comment: I have a temp "DataTable" An my information goes to my "DataTable", That's where I am tryin to get the information from